# Partial View on Submit using Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitfileform").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/html;charset=utf-8',
            dataType:'html',
            success:function (result) {
                $('#tablepartialview').html(result);
            },
            error:function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            }
        })


        });
</script>
```

and here is html.beginform,

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("PropertyColumnMap", "ImportFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form single-col",id="submitfileform"}))
{
                    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" value=""/>
                    <select id="assetlist" name="assetlist">
                          <option>...</option></select>

                   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitfile"/>
}
<div id="tablepartialview">


</div>
```

What happens is, on submit, I get the partial view of the same page 'Index' in div-'tablepartialview', instead of another page 'PropertyColumnMap', which I want. After the ajax call is done,it redirects to action 'PropertyColumnMap', and then I get the view for PropertyColumnMap.

```
public ActionResult PropertyColumnMap(FormCollection f, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {

            String fileid = Import(uploadFile);



                var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(Session[fileid].ToString());
                excel.DatabaseEngine = DatabaseEngine.Ace;
                var workSheetName = excel.GetWorksheetNames().Last();
                var assetname = f["assetlist"].ToString();
                Mapping(assetname, workSheetName, fileid);


            return PartialView("PropertyColumnMap");


        }
```

Comment: if i specify a url like this, url: ImportFile/PropertyColumn, it goes to the action but I am not able to get httppostedfilebase .It gives null.

Comment: As you are using MVC, have you tried `Ajax.BeginForm` instead and get it to do all the work for you? You don't need any of your JQuery as it does all the basics for Ajax form submission.

Answer (score 0):

If its possible please include following js to your project

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

Then you can use

```
$("#submitfileform").ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'POST',
        success:function (result) {
            $('#tablepartialview').html(result);
        },
        error:function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
           });
```

Comment: Not much point adding extra JQuery plugins when MVC provide `Ajax.BeginForm` to do ajax-based form submissions without adding *any* client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MVC, just switch your `Html.BeginForm` to use the Ajaxified `Ajax.BeginForm` instead.

It allows for many options including specifying the id of the target element to update (e.g. 'tablepartialview').

### e.g.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PropertyColumnMap", "ImportFile", new AjaxOptions(){ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "tablepartialview"}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form single-col", id = "submitfileform" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" value="" />
    <select id="assetlist" name="assetlist">
        <option>...</option>
    </select>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitfile" />
}
<div id="tablepartialview">
</div>
```

You probably have to install the Ajax unobtrusive NuGet package to provide the wiring, but it is quite simple and does not require you to write any extra JQuery for the view.